# My phonegap app displays but I can't click on anything

Tags: javascript, cordova, splash-screen

I have a phonegap app that redirects to an external page. The external page loads just fine but I can't click on anything and I can't scroll. I've whitelisted the address and the page does load, I just can't click. Does javascript get disabled on external pages? Or could something else be blocking it? I've stripped down my code to just the redirect and still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that when I copied my config.xml from another app I built, I had left in

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

I hadn't defined a splash screen for this app yet. Basically, an invisible splash screen was covering my content making it impossible to click on anything even though I could see the content.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to this config.xml tag:

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x77ffffff"/>
```

Removing it fixed the app. Think it does not work well in iOS